# Flex айтемы не влазят в контейнер на ios 8 и ниже. Почему?

Tags: вёрстка, кроссбраузерность

Есть такой вот код:

```css
.services {
  padding: 120px 0;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.services__content {
  margin-top: 64px;
}

.services__list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.services__item {
  width: 32%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.services__item:not(:nth-child(3n)) {
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.services__item-icon {
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 54px;
  width: 54px;
  margin-right: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #35373e;
}

.services__wrap-text {
  width: 270px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.services__item-title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  color: #000000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .services {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .services__list {
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .services .services__item {
    width: 48%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .services__wrap-text {
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .services__item-icon {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  .services__item-title {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .services {
    padding-top: 80px;
  }
  .services__list {
    display: block;
  }
  .services .services__item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .services__wrap-text {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .services {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="services">
    <div class="inner-page">
      <div class="section__wrap-title">
        <h2 class="services__title">1</h2>
        <p class="services__title-text section__title-text">1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="services__content">
        <ul class="services__list">
          <li class="services__item">
            <div class="services__item-icon">
              <svg class="services__icon" width="25" height="30"><use xlink:href="img/svg/all-sprite.svg#icon-mobile-alt" /></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="services__wrap-text">
              <h3 class="services__item-title">Адаптивность, Responsive</h3>
              <p class="services__item-text">Адаптивная и отзывчивая верстка под разные типы устройств.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="services__item">
            <div class="services__item-icon">
              <svg class="services__icon" width="30" height="30"><use xlink:href="img/svg/all-sprite.svg#icon-internet-explorer" /></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="services__wrap-text">
              <h3 class="services__item-title">Кроссбраузерность</h3>
              <p class="services__item-text">Одинаковое отображение сайта во всех браузерах, включая IE11 и выше.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="services__item">
            <div class="services__item-icon">
              <svg class="services__icon" width="30" height="35"><use xlink:href="img/svg/all-sprite.svg#icon-html5" /></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="services__wrap-text">
              <h3 class="services__item-title">Валидность и семантика</h3>
              <p class="services__item-text">Код соостветствует стандартам консорциума W3C.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="services__item">
            <div class="services__item-icon">
              <svg class="services__icon" width="35" height="30"><use xlink:href="img/svg/all-sprite.svg#icon-code" /></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="services__wrap-text">
              <h3 class="services__item-title">Аккуратный и продуманный код</h3>
              <p class="services__item-text">Верстаю по БЭМ методологии, поэтому код легко поддерживается.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="services__item">
            <div class="services__item-icon">
              <svg class="services__icon" width="35" height="30"><use xlink:href="img/svg/all-sprite.svg#icon-money" /></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="services__wrap-text">
              <h3 class="services__item-title">Цена / Качество</h3>
              <p class="services__item-text">Качественная и сравнительно недорогая верстка. Работаю без предоплат.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="services__item">
            <div class="services__item-icon">
              <svg class="services__icon" width="30" height="30"><use xlink:href="img/svg/all-sprite.svg#icon-headset" /></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="services__wrap-text">
              <h3 class="services__item-title">Постоянная связь</h3>
              <p class="services__item-text">Всегда готов ответить на вопросы или обсудить работу.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Видно, что все item позиционируются, как надо. Но при ios 8 и меньше .services__wrap-text выпадает из контейнера. Я все пробовал, flex: 0 1 auto, width: auto, flex-basis. Он просто как деревянный засох намертво. Тупо не хочет сужаться по контейнеру. Я не знаю, что с эти делать. И такое со всеми дочерними элементами flexbox...
[image: Изображение проблемы: синий бордер - контейнер, красный - services__wrap-text]

Comment: Не оно? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986668/flex-wrap-not-working-as-expected-in-safari

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, благодарю, именно то, что надо. И самое забавное, что я же находил вроде эту ссылку, когда искал проблемы в интернете. Пропусти мимо глаз такой ответ: flex: 1 0 auto;